# How to solve thread starvation?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following locking mechanism for my class. When I run this program, one thread continuously acquires and reacquires the lock without giving any of the other threads a chance at acquiring the lock, leading to starvation. How can I restructure my locking mechanism such that once a thread gives up a lock, another one acquires it? I'd like to see other threads acquire the lock and not have to wait until the one that has the lock stops running.

```
  private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
  private final Condition condition = lock.newCondition();

  private final Map<Integer, Long> locksMap = new HashMap<Integer, Long>();

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public long lock(int recNo) throws RecordNotFoundException {
    ValidationUtils.checkNegative(recNo);

    lock.lock();
    long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    try {
      while (locksMap.get(recNo) != null) {
        try {
          System.out.println("Thread " + id + " is waiting.");
          condition.await();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
          return -1;
        }
      }
      Long prevValue = locksMap.put(recNo, id);
      if (prevValue != null) {
        String msg = "Expected no value for " + recNo + " but was ";
        msg += prevValue + ".";
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
      }
      System.out.println("Thread " + id + " has the lock.");
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
    return id;
  }

  /** {@inheritDoc} */
  @Override
  public void unlock(int recNo, long cookie) throws RecordNotFoundException, SecurityException {
    ValidationUtils.checkNegative(recNo);
    if (cookie < 0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("cookie is negative.");
    }

    lock.lock();
    try {
      if (locksMap.get(recNo) == cookie) {
        locksMap.remove(recNo);
      }
      else {
        String msg = "Wrong lock cookie. Expected " + locksMap.get(recNo);
         msg += ", was " + cookie + ".";
        throw new IllegalStateException(msg);
      }
      long id = Thread.currentThread().getId();
      System.out.println("Thread " + id + " no longer has the lock.");
      condition.signalAll();
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tests the locking mechanism in this class.
   * 
   * @param args None.
   */
  public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(5);
    final Data data = new Data();
    Runnable task = new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
            long cookie = data.lock(1);
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Do something.
            data.unlock(1, cookie);
          }
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
          e.getStackTrace();
        }
        catch (RecordNotFoundException e) {
          e.getStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
          e.getStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
          latch.countDown();
        }
      }
    };
    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
      threadPool.execute(task);
    }
    try {
      latch.await();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.getStackTrace();
    }
    threadPool.shutdown();
  }
```

Here's the output. Note that Thread 9 will stop acquiring the lock only after the loop finishes.

```
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 9 has the lock.
Thread 13 is waiting.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 9 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 13 has the lock.
Thread 12 is waiting.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 13 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 12 has the lock.
Thread 11 is waiting.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 12 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 11 has the lock.
Thread 10 is waiting.
Thread 11 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
Thread 10 has the lock.
Thread 10 no longer has the lock.
```

Comment: If this is an issue I would suggest trying lockless operations. This works best in simple cases, but if you can do this you avoid locking issues and can speed up the code significiantly.

Comment: I don't understand how such problems arise anyway.  Can anyone suggest an example of a read-world app where this might be an issue?  OS tend to give priority boosts to threads that have been waiting on a lock anyway, so..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `ReetrantLock` with Fair policy. Fair policy avoid thread starvation.

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
```

Java doc

> public ReentrantLock(boolean fair)
>   Creates an instance of ReentrantLock with the given fairness policy.
>   Parameters:
>   fair - true if this lock will be fair; else false

Comment: +1! Actually forcing fairness within the lock implementation is a much better option than trying to get fairness with sleeping/yielding.

Answer (score 6):

I know you already have an acceptable answer, but I just want to add my 2¢.

If you're running on a single core machine or maybe even a dual core machine or something the problem could simply be that the JVM isn't swapping threads often enough to give another thread a chance at the lock.

In any case, simply calling [`Thread.yield()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#yield%28%29) after releasing the lock should be sufficient to allow the other threads a chance to acquire the lock before the original thread grabs it again.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, locks should not be hold for long time. So

```
        long cookie = data.lock(1);
        Thread.sleep(1000); // Do something.
        data.unlock(1, cookie);
```

is unacceptable. This way always only one thread would be "do something" each moment. Even if you add yeild() or sleep() as suggested, throughput performance remain the same. You should aquire lock, retrieve a task, release lock and only then "do something" .

Comment: Yeah, I agree. That was a bad example on my part. The task that the thread will be doing won't take that long.

Answer (score 0):

Once a thread gives up a lock, why not use Thread.sleep(int millis) to have it sleep long enough for another Thread to pick it up?

Comment: You're right. I added `Thread.sleep(1000)` after the call to `unlock`, and other threads were acquiring the lock. So it could be a timing issue then? I guess the thread that gave up the lock was quick enough to reacquire it again.

Comment: Sleeping for a whole second is a _long time_ in terms of CPU cycles. If you cut it down to even 100ms I think that would still be plenty of delay, but cause less of a performance hit. It looks like you only have a few threads, so unless the stuff in the lock is pretty intense then you'll probably end up spending a good percentage of your time with all threads sleeping if you use 1000ms.

Comment: The better solution is using ReetrantLock with fair policy and java takes care that thread starvation will not happen.

Comment: This is a BAD idea, IMO.  Using `sleep` (or even `yield`) to influence the scheduling is liable to make your application sluggish due to a different kind of starvation.

Comment: Downvoted b/c this answer should not be positive for reasons as outlined in other comments.

Comment: Sleeping is always a  bad idea. It slows down the whole process and is usually unpredictable.